# Python3 - Urllib2 | Need to remove the "User-Agent" header completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2

I need to remove the User-Agent from the header of an Urllib-Request in Python3, but if I do following, then it still transmits the User-Agent, just without a value.

```
url = "xxx"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": ""
}

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

The problem is, that I need to have the User-Agent completely remove from the header, not just with an empty string, so that isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) in php would return false.

Thanks,
Lennart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the following fixed my problem.

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": None
}
```

Unfortunately I had to switch from Urllib2 to the "requests" module, because with Urllib, using "None" has thrown an error.

Thanks anyway for all the replies!

Answer (score 2):

You could build your own opener and remove `'User-Agent'` header:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [(header, value)
                     for header, value in opener.addheaders
                     if header.casefold() != 'user-agent']

with opener.open(url) as response:
    handle(response)
```

Comment: I'm a few years late, but this is absolutely the correct answer.  Modifying the `OpenerDirector` instance's `addheaders` values is actually included in the [example section of urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples).